# Почему кружки расставляются неправильно?

Tags: javascript, css

Я ожидаю получить круги в местах, которые указаны стрелками, а получаю то, что в примере.

Где я ошибся?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var points = 3;
var angle = 360 / points;
var R = 100;
var main = document.getElementById('main');

for (var i = 0; i < points; i++) {


  var currentAngle = angle * i;
  console.log(currentAngle)


  var leftOffset = R - R * Math.cos(currentAngle) + 'px';
  var topOffset = R - R * Math.sin(currentAngle) + 'px';




  var some = document.createElement('div');
  some.classList.add('some');
  some.style.left = leftOffset;
  some.style.top = topOffset;

  main.appendChild(some);
}
```

```css
#main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.some {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

</div>
```

Comment: Math.sin и Math.cos принимают в качестве аргумента не градусы, а радианы.

Comment: @Darth, почему не ответом?:)